# python + json: parse to list

Tags: python, json, list, parsing

I'm somewhat new to parsing JSON data with python (using python 2.7). There is a service that I have to send API calls to, and the JSON response is something like what I have below. the amount of items in 'row' can vary. What I need to do is take only the 'content' from the second line IF there is a second line, and put it into a list. Essentially, it is a list of only the 'campaign confirmation numbers' and nothing else. the number will also always be only 9 numeric numbers if that helps anything. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

```
{"response":
    {"result":
        {"Potentials":
            {"row":
                [
                {"no":"1","FL":
                    {"content":"523836000004148171","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                },
                {"no":"2","FL":
                    {"content":"523836000004924051","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                },
                {"no":"3","FL":
                    [
                    {"content":"523836000005318448","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                    {"content":"694275295","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                    ]
                },
                {"no":"4","FL":
                    [
                    {"content":"523836000005318662","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                    {"content":"729545274","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                    ]
                },
                {"no":"5","FL":
                    [
                    {"content":"523836000005318663","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                    {"content":"903187021","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                    ]
                },
                {"no":"6","FL":
                    {"content":"523836000005322387","val":"POTENTIALID"}
                },
                {"no":"7","FL":
                    [
                    {"content":"523836000005332558","val":"POTENTIALID"},
                    {"content":"729416761","val":"Campaign Confirmation Number"}
                    ]
                }
                ]
            }
        },
    "uri":"/crm/private/json/Potentials/getSearchRecords"}
}
```

EDIT: an example of the output for this example would be:

confs = [694275295, 729545274, 903187021, 729416761]

or

confs = ['694275295', '729545274', '903187021', '729416761']

it really doesn't matter if they're stored as strings or ints

EDIT 2: here's my code snip:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import datetime
import json

key = '[removed]'

params = {
    '[removed]'
    }

final_URL = 'https://[removed]'
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = urllib2.Request(final_URL,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()

j = json.load(content)

confs = []
for no in j["response"]["result"]["Potentials"]["row"]:
    data = no["FL"]
    if isinstance(data, list) and len(data) > 1:
        confs.append(int(data[1]["content"]))

print confs
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the output you need according to this example?

Comment: just added the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `j` is your JSON object which the above structure has been parsed into:

```
>>> results = []
>>> for no in j["response"]["result"]["Potentials"]["row"]:
...     data = no["FL"]
...     if isinstance(data, list) and len(data) > 1:
...         results.append(int(data[1]["content"]))
...
>>> results
[694275295, 729545274, 903187021, 729416761]
```

Comment: looks like I am getting an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. i've added the snippet of my code into my post.

Comment: @user3126085: You first need to parse the string that holds the JSON information using `json.load()` (from a file) or `json.loads()` (from a string).

Comment: @user3126085: You need to use `json.loads()`, as I wrote above. Not `load()` because that only works on file objects.

Comment: ooooh jesus. my bad. fixed, and works perfect! thank you so much!

Comment: one thing i noticed is if there are duplicate values it stores all of them with an "L" at the end. i checked the raw JSON response, and they are fine there. would you know how to fix that? here's an example: [694275295, 729545274, 5915342892L, 5915342892L] ... EDIT... changing the append to a string got rid of the "L"'s

Comment: @user3126085: Yes, if you're on Python 2 and parse the numbers to integers, they will be stored as long integers. The `L` is only visible if you look at the representation of the values, it doesn't interfere with calculations or `print`ing, though.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that 'response' holds the json string:

```
import json

data = json.loads(response)
rows = data['response']['result']['Potentials']['rows']
output = []
for row in rows:
    contents = row['FL']
    if len(contents) > 1:
        output.append(contents[1]['content'])
```

That should do it.

EDIT:

I finally got some time to test this "one liner". It's fun to use Python's functional features:

```
import json

#initialize response to your string
data = json.loads(response)
rows = data['response']['result']['Potentials']['row']
output = [x['FL'][1]['content'] for x in rows if isinstance(x['FL'], list) and len(x['FL']) > 1]
print output

['694275295', '729545274', '903187021', '729416761']
```

Comment: That won't work because if there is only one element, it's not enclosed in a list, so `len()` will also return `2` because the dictionary has two items in it.